# Mostrar contenido de campo select con datos obtenidos desde una BD (JSON y JQUERY) a partir de la segunda fila agregada dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario en el cuál hay una fila (un ítem) por defecto, y en dicha fila hay un select llamado `description`, el contenido (opciones del select) es obtenido desde una base de datos, enviados a la vista a través de ajax en formato JSON y funciona, el problema está cuando agrego a partir de la segunda fila de manera dinámica, no me mustra los datos del select.

Mi formulario con la fila por defecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al agregar la fila dinámica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola no obtengo ningún error, me imagino que el problema se debe a que una vez que carga la página como lo indica el código `$(document).ready(function(){` muestra los datos del select, pero al agregar la fila dinámica no lo hace porque no sé como indicarle al Jquery que lo haga.

Mi controlador

```
public function select()
{
    $services = Service::all();

    if (!$services->isEmpty()) {

        foreach ($services as $service) {
            if($service->type == 1)
            {
              $elements[] = array('value'=>$service->id,'description'=>$service->description, 'type'=>$service->type);  
            }
        }

        return $json = json_encode($elements);
    }
}
```

Mi ajax

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "{{ route('select') }}",
      data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
      success: function(data) {
        datos = $.parseJSON(data);
        for(var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            $('#service_id').append('<option value = \"' + datos[i].value + '\">' + datos[i].description + '</option>');
        }
      },
      error: function (error) { 
        console.log(error); 
      }
                               
    });  
    
  });                                  
</script>
```

Mi Jquery con el que agrego la fila dinámicamente

```
newRow: function () {
    jQuery(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td><div class="delete-btn"><input class="form-control qty" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" value="1" type="text" readonly="readonly"><a class=' + $.opt.delete.substring(1) + ' href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><select class="form-control" name="service_id[]" id="service_id" onchange=changePrice();></select></td><td><input class="form-control date" type="text" name="date[]" id="datepicker" placeholder="Select" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type=\'text\')"></td><td><select class="form-control" name="time[]"><option value="" selected>Select</option><option value="06:00">06:00</option><option value="06:30">06:30</option><option value="07:00">07:00</option><option value="07:30">07:30</option><option value="08:00">08:00</option></select></td><td><input class="form-control price" name="price[]" id="price[]" placeholder="Precio" type="number"></td><td><span class="total">0.00</span></td></tr>');
    
    if (jQuery($.opt.delete).length > 0) {
        jQuery($.opt.delete).show();
    }

    return 1;
},
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento llamas a `newRow`, y como lo haces?

Comment: Hola, con el botón `Agregar Ítem` este es el enlace `<a id="addRow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar ítem</a>`

Comment: Tengo un script que llama al Jquery, `<script> jQuery(document).ready(function(){  jQuery().invoice({ addRow : "#addRow" });  }); </script>`

Comment: Desconozco el método `invoice()` en **jQuery**, creo que si vas a tu consola veras un error como: `jQuery().invoice is not a function`. En caso de estar usando un **plugin** por favor especificalo en tu pregunta, todo eso debería estar en tu pregunta

Comment: `invoice()` es un método personalizado, el Jquery es un archivo que tiene muchas líneas de código, por eso no lo compartí pero aquí está el inicio `function Invoice() { self = this; } Invoice.prototype = { constructor: Invoice,`

Comment: Okey creo que el plugin que estas usando [es este](https://github.com/firoz-ahmad-likhon/jquery-invoice-plugin), ¿Correcto?

Comment: Sí, exactamente... Ese es el plugin

Comment: Alguna recomendación?